# How do I determine the type of an element in a struct in a C macro?

Tags: c, macros

I am creating a dynamic array in C. I also want to create a function that initializes a given dynamic array with a certain number of elements. However, in determining the size of each element for the memory allocation, I don't know what exactly to do.

Here is my code:

```c
#define typedef_list(name, type)    \
        typedef struct {            \
                int cap;            \
                int n;              \
                type *items;        \
        } name;                                                                                             

#define list_init(list, cap)                                                              \
        do {                                                                              \
                list.items = malloc(cap * sizeof(*list.items));   /* problem line */  \
                list.cap = cap;                                                        \
        } while (0);

#endif
```

I use `sizeof(*list.items)` to get the sizeof whatever is being pointed to. It seems to work, as the following macro works for a given type:

```c
#define list_test(list) do { printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*(list.items))); } while(0);
```

Is this acceptable to do, as the memory technically hasn't been allocated yet? My guess is that the compiler isn't trying to access that memory and instead just "knows" the size, but is this fine?

Edit - here is the code I use to test this:

```c
typedef_list(dyn, uint16_t);  // works with any given type

int main(void) {
        dyn arr; 
        list_test(arr);
}
```

Comment: You don't need memory allocated for the compiler to know the size. It hasn't even been allocated at compile time, when `sizeof` is usually evaluated. The `sizeof` does not give the size of a memory allocation but of the *type*.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Can you put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question about using macros marked "problem line". I don't know why you are doing that. Only use a macro when really necessary otherwise you might write unreadable code.

Comment: The question was about is using that kind of syntax in the `sizeof` is okay. I'll edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Why not just use `void *items` and cast back to the correct type when accessing?

Comment: You should add parentheses to your expression argument `cap`, e.g. change change `cap * sizeof(*list.items)` to `(cap) * sizeof(*list.items)`.  Without them, consider what would happen if you passed something like `n+1` for `cap`.  This is standard good practice for C macros.

Comment: ... and similar for argument `list`.  As a general rule, all references to a macro's arguments in that macro's replacement text should always be enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question: yes, it is ok to write `sizeof(*(list.items))` even if `list.items` has not yet been allocated since the result of `sizeof` only depends on the type of the operand and the operand is not evaluated unless it is of variable length array type (which it cannot be in this case).

This is specified in the C17 Standard 6.5.3.4-2:

> The **sizeof** operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the
> parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result
> is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated;
> otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

In fact, a general method to get the size of a struct member `M` of a struct with type `T` without having an instance of the struct is to use `sizeof` with a null pointer of type `T *` as follows:

```
#define sizeofMember(T, M) sizeof(((T *) 0)->M)
```